# change two UL list position in jquery by drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

jsfiddle.net/ZySSb

i need jquery code for this
i have to do is that when i can drag item1 from sortable1 ul and drop to item6 sortable2 ul then [sortable2's item6 can place on sortable1's item1 and same sortable 1's item1 can place on sortable 2's item 6]

```
         </head>
<body>
  <ul id="sortable1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable2" >
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/... Just a bit googling, and you find it... Try to do something by yourself before expecting others to give you a "ready made" code ...

Comment: i have to swap position's of both ul's with each

Comment: and what did you try so far ?

Comment: when drag a list from one ul and drop on second ul's list then both ul's li can swap

Comment: post your jquery code, or better, create a fiddle, then someone may be able to help you